# Flask SocketIo application not working when deployed on Heroku

Tags: javascript, flask, heroku, socket.io, flask-socketio

I am having a hard time deploying a real-time chat application on Heroku. The application runs smoothly on the local machine.

On Heroku however, I keep getting this error:

```
Blocked loading mixed active content “http://my-app.herokuapp.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1594923543323-0” 
socket.io.min.js:1:30684
```

I am including relevant portions of the code:

**index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.3.6/socket.io.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"  src="{{url_for('static', filename= 'scripts/index.js')}}"></script>
```

I'm not sure but I think making a mistake in the way I include the CDN script.

**index.js**:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
        var protocol = window.location.protocol;
        socket= io.connect(protocol + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
      
        socket.on('connect', function(){
            socket.send("Am I connected to you server?");
            socket.emit('join', {'name' : username});
})}
```

****init**.py**:

```
from flask_socketio import SocketIO  
socketio= SocketIO()  
def create_app(config_class= Config):  
    app= Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config= True)  
    socketio.init_app(app)
```

**routes.py**:

```
@socketio.on('join')
def handle_join(data):
    
    current_user= User.query.filter_by(username = data['name']).first()
    room= current_user.id
    join_room(room)
    send('you are now joined, ' + current_user.username, room= room)
```

**Procfile**:

```
web: gunicorn chatbox:app
```

I am using eventlet for asynchronous services.
I am quite new to web development and I will appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Are you using the http or https URL on Heroku? There appears to be a mix of secure and non-secure requests going out from your HTML page, that is basically the issue.

Comment: @Miguel https url.
Also, sometimes the reserved events 'connect', 'message' work just fine but the custom socketio events never do.

Comment: The error log that you show indicates the socket connection is going out to an http:// URL though.